# how to upload image file to FTP server in swift?

Tags: swift, ftp, image-uploading

I am using [Gold Raccoon](https://github.com/albertodebortoli/GoldRaccoon) in my swift project. My swift code builds and runs fine but when I check on the FTP Server there is no file.
This is the code which I am using in viewDidload()

```
  var ftpRequest:GRRequestsManager!
  var  path  = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("marker", ofType: ".png")

  ftpRequest = GRRequestsManager(hostname: "192.x.x.x", user: "xx", password: "xxxx")
  ftpRequest.addRequestForUploadFileAtLocalPath(path, toRemotePath: "/marker.png")
  self.ftpRequest.startProcessingRequests()
```

Then I tried to check whether my file is successully uploaded or not by using delegate of GRRequestsManager `ftpRequest.delegate = self` in viewDidload().
and wrote these delegate functions in my swift class by conforming with
**GRRequestsManagerDelegate** protocol.

```
 func requestsManager(requestsManager: GRRequestsManagerProtocol!, didCompleteUploadRequest request: GRDataExchangeRequestProtocol!) {
            print("did Complete Upload Request")
        }
   func requestsManager(requestsManager: GRRequestsManagerProtocol!, didFailRequest request: GRRequestProtocol!, withError error: NSError!) {
            print("did Fail Request")
        }
```

when I compile its fine but when I run the code xcode gives me an error on this line `ftpRequest.delegate = self`

> unexpectedly found nil

I cannot upload my .png file to the FTP Server. Allover the internet that I found is about Obj-C but NO swift code to do this.

Is there any swift way to do this?

Please guide me If I am doing wrong. Or provide any running sample code that uploads the .png file to the FTP Server with Authentication(should require username and password)

**NOTE**: I am using Briding Header to use **GoldRaccoon** (as it is available only in Objective-C)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally my problem is solved I just used [Rebekka](https://github.com/Constantine-Fry/rebekka) Touch framework which is a swift framework. Its is easy to use and really a very good thing.

Comment: I used Rebekka to uploaded image on FTP server, but now I want to show progressBar to uploaded image in swift iOS.